# vector subscript out of range - bubble sort - improved

Tags: c++, vector, sorting

I've got this piece of code that implements a bubble sorting of an array.
Being compiled in MS VS 2012 it works up to a point:

UPD: I've added a lot of checking to trace the exact place where a crash happens, an it's like this:
it swaps the first two elements of an array, prints out an array with those elements swapped, then it prints out "Checking" and crashes with "vector subscript out of range"

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int Check(vector<int> Array)
{
printf ("Checking: \n");
for (int i = 0; i < Array.size(); i++)
    if((int*) Array[i] == NULL)
    {
        cerr << "Array [" << i << "] is fubared";
        return -1;
    }
}

int PrintOut(vector<int> Array)
{
printf ("Your array appears to be as follows: \n");
for (int i = 0; i < Array.size(); i++)
    printf("%d  ", Array[i]);
return 0;
}

int bubble_sort()
{
int or_size = 2;
int i, j, size, temp;

printf("Specify array size\n");
scanf_s("%d", &size);
printf(" Now, input all elements of the array \n");

vector<int> Array(size, 0);
if (size > or_size)
    Array.resize(size);

for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    printf("Array [%d] is now re-initialised as ", i);
    scanf_s("%d", &temp);
    printf("\n");
    Array[i] = temp;
}

Check(Array);

PrintOut(Array);

for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < size-i ; j--)
    {
        printf ("Attempting to swap Array[%d], which = %d, and Array [%d], which = %d \n",j, Array[j], j+1, Array[j+1]);
        if (Array[j] > Array[j+1])
        {
            Array[j]+=Array[j+1];
            Array[j+1] = Array[j] - Array[j+1];
            Array[j] = Array[j] - Array[j+1];
            printf("Swapped \n");
        }
        PrintOut(Array);
        Check(Array);
    }

printf ("\n Your Array has been bubble_sorted and should know look like this: \n");
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%d ", Array[i]);

Array.clear();

return 0;
}

int main()
{
    bubble_sort();
    return 0;
}
```

It must be something really simple, but just out of my reach.

PS
No embarrassing _asm now ;-)

Comment: `if((int*) Array[i] == NULL)` why you are doing so?!

Comment: well, I suspect that if it really is ==NULL, something is wrong.

Comment: Why null? Why not `Array[i] == 0`?

Comment: Array[i] should == whatever I input, whereas a pointer to Array[i] should be some integer. If it isn't, then something is wrong with this element.

Comment: The cast of `Array[i]` from `int` to `int*` is definitely wrong. You don't take the address of a value by casting to the pointer type, but by using the address operator: `&(Array[i])`.

Comment: The way you swap two array values is more complicated and almost certainly slower than simply using a third temporary variable. Both the XOR and arithmetic swap "tricks" look cute but they're bad code. Since you're using C++ why not use `std::swap` that's part of the language library?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a bit odd to me, it is better and more to use `cout` and `cin` instead of `printf` and `scanf` but beside that you have something like this:

```
for (j = 0; j < size-i ; j--) {...}
```

so for first item `j` is 0 and then it will decremented to -1 and since `operator[]` of `vector` take `std::size_t` and it is an unsigned type it will be interpreted as 0xFFFFFFFF and this is a really large value and large index much larger than your vector size and hence you get "vector subscript out of range"

Comment: thanks, I'll look into that. It sounds so simple that it should be right.

Comment: Yeah, you were right: it should've been j++ really. Now it works perfectly well. Thanks a lot